# Templating a typedef Statement

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I am attempting to template a stack class and in the implementation of the class in the seperate file there is this line.

```
typedef [namespace]::stack<double> number_stack;
```

I am attempting to template this so that it will accept the generic T type.

The end goal then, would be to make it such that the templated type would allow for complex numbers as entries on the stack.

Could anyone help me with this issue please?

Comment: Do you mean `typedef N::stack<int> number_stack;` ? If not then please clarify your question

Answer (score 2):

If you want `number_stack` to typedef a specific instantiation of template `stack`, just go

```
typedef stack<int> number_stack;
```

If you want the typedef `number_stack` itself "to be templated", you need c++11 [type alias](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

```
template < typename T > class stack {};

template < typename T > using number_stack = stack < T >;

typedef number_stack<int> int_stack;
```

This use of `using` is basically making the standard `typedef` templated.

Comment: And, just for completeness, the C++ < 11 way of doing this is `template <typename T> struct number_stack { typedef stack<T> type; };` which you would use like `typename number_stack<int>::type an_int_stack;`

Comment: @cdhowie You don't need that `typename` there for `an_int_stack`.

Comment: @T.C. You are right, I was running low on caffeine. :)